# I want to block certain characters in javascript validation?

Tags: asp.net, .net, javascript

I want to block ][#{}'". But somehow I'm not able to put it in my code. What should I declare in place of val. Also when I put val = /^[0-9]+$/;. It blocks numbers when I put them alone. But when I concatenate a number with an alphabet, it gets accepted. For ex- abc123 gets accepted whereas 123 does not.

```
function Allvalidate()
{
    var input;
    var controlId = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");
    input = controlId.value;
    var val = //????//
    if (input == "") 
    {
        alert("Please Enter a Value" + "\n");
        return false;
    }
    else if (val.test(input)) 
    {        
        alert("It does not accept these characters" + "\n");
        return false;         
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == [here you can write the key code of the characters that you want allow]) {
         // TO DO Your Logic
    }
});
```

Here I  have used e.which and  e.keycode because of browser compatibility [ firefox and IE may give the different code]

I hope this will work . .